# Android device is listed and recognized using adb, Hardware Overview but won't show in Finder?

Tags: adb, macos

I'm using a Macbook Pro OS X Sierra, with Android File Transfer installed. When plugging in an Asus Zenfone 2, a popup shows with the message (minus the Initialize button):

[image: The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer]

However, this is followed immediately with another window listing the contents of said phone, with buttons for both Internal Storage and SD Card. Drag and Drop/Copy-Paste file transfers are possible as well (not my screenshot but very similar to mine):

[image]

Also, when checking System Information in About This Mac/Overview/System Report/USB, "Android" is visible under the USB Device Tree. Clicking this further shows additional data such as Product and Vendor IDs, etc. (image not mine but similar):

[image]

When in Terminal, typing "adb devices" will list the device's Vendor ID.

Long story short, the device is recognized *except in Finder.*

Any suggestions how to make the device appear in Finder's Sidebar, under Devices? Any help would greatly be appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Its probably about mtp mode or another usb conection mode set it in your android decixe settings or find a program to moint mtp volumes

Comment: Yes, I've tried the mtp/ptp mode (forgot to mention that) but you've given me an idea about mounting volumes. Thanks, mate.